# Screen flashing when certain programs are focused

Tags: firefox, windows-8.1, display, battery, flashing

My laptop screen is sometime flashing when it is battery powered. While I can live with it, what puzzles me is that it flashes under certain conditions (and not always):

- When on battery and Firefox is in full size window (stops flashing if I reduce the size of the window to anything less than the maximum size), only produce flashes with some websites;
- When Visual Studio 2012 is in full size and big size window (about more than 4/5 of the screen).

All my drivers are up to date. The model is a Samsung 550P7C T03. The graphic cards are the Intel HD4000 and an NVidia GeForce GT630M. I know the battery might be damaged over time; I simply don't understand why some programs cause the flashing.

So in the end, I am not so much looking into solving the issue but more to understand the mechanic behind. After all, it could well be a bug in Samsung's drivers...

**EDIT :**

Actually, the screen alternates between what seems to be max and min brightness. The battery mode is the "normal setting" of Windows 8.1 and the brightness is supposed to be set at 50%.

Comment: Can you be more precise in what you mean by flashing? On first thought this seems to be a power management issue where the flashing is setting the brightness of the screen due to how much power is consumed, so changing the power settings should allow it to stop. But given that I have no idea what you mean by flashes, I may be wrong. (and as such I haven't posted this as an answer yet)

Comment: Well you are right actually, never thought of it this way! The screen seems to be actually changing rapidly from max to min brightness. My battery mode is the "normal" setting of Windows and I have only changed the parameters of the case when it is connected, not when it is on battery. I will edit the question to make it clear, thanks.

Comment: Can you set the brightness a lower setting and prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your power management options, and select the profile: High performance. Then tweak the `on battery` part to your liking. Note that even if you would tweak it similar to the `balanced` setting, it will still do weird stuff to consume energy.

For example, I use intensive programs for making music, and on the normal setting, I can't even play back some of my songs. After setting to high performance, it all works fine.

Comment: Any idea why this behaviour is present? Actually, I have read that keeping the Max performance mode on battery is bad since the instant current drain might exceed the nominal current drain necessary to ensure the (relative) long life of the battery...

Comment: Try it first and see if it solves it, then look for ways to get it solved better. I use all laptops with maximum performance, never had any problems with it.

Comment: Ok will give a look and keep you updated ;)